# How to use declare Stream as return type when dealing with JPA Specification and spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm wondering if I can use JPA specification predicates in custom queries?

I've tried but with no success.

Let's say I have an Entity `Customer` and a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>,
   JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer> {
}
```

Querying like this is OK

```
@Query("select c from Customer c")
Stream<Customer> streamAllCustomers();
```

This is Not OK

```
Stream<Customer> streamAllCustomersWithFilter(Specification<Customer> filter);
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

NB I know I can put params in the `@Query` but I would like to stay in the design of the current app and use Specifications all the way.

Comment: No such thing as "JPA Specification"; that is Spring Data JPA API only (!= JPA API). Tags fixed

Comment: You have a different question in your title and in the body of your question. Which one do you want us to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

No, and No, but manually Yes

I think [issue DATAJPA-906](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-906) answers both of your questions

1. Question (from the title): **How to use declare Stream as return type when dealing with JPA Specification and spring-data-jpa?**

You don't, at least not in a directly supported way:

> Support Java 8 Streams on JpaSpecificationExecutor
>
> [..]
>
> This unfortunately will have to wait for a 2.0 revamp as a Stream in the method signature would render the interface unloadable on versions of Java < 8.

Of course you can always [add your custom methods including implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

2. Question **Can I use JPA specification predicates in custom queries?** (custom queries being queries defined using the `@Query` annotation

> how would you even combine a CriteriaQuery defined through a Specification and a manually defined JPQL query?

In case the problem is not clear: If your custom query contains an inner select, wher should the Criteria from the specification go?

**What you can do**

Implement a custom method, returning a Stream and taking a specification as an argument, combine it with prepared specifications to call an existing method of the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface and convert the result to a `Stream`

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the spring-data-jpa issue, i will wait for 2.x for a maybe "cleaner" implementation :)

Answer (score 7):

There is the way to stream data from Spring Data JPA that I use. 
This approach is useful to process huge amount of data while avoiding high memory consumption, because whole query result is not loaded to memory.

Create [custom individual repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) with following implementation

```
public class YourCustomRepositoryImpl implements YourCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "yorEntityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Stream<SomeEntity> streamAll(Specification<SomeEntity> spec) {

            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<SomeEntity> query = cb.createQuery(SomeEntity.class);
            Root<SomeEntity> root = query.from(SomeEntity.class);
            query.where(spec.toPredicate(root, query, cb));

            return em.createQuery(query).getResultStream();
    }
```

}

Sure, this requires JPA 2.2 supporting ORM framework (I used Hibernate 5.3).

Also, you should care to provide a connection to be alive while stream is being processed.